# Why aren't my PowerShell quotes escaping properly

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I'm trying to assign a PowerShell variable to part of a command (a `Git` command) that I want to call elsewhere. I have this line:

```
$gitExe = "`"$env:programfiles\Git\bin\git.exe`" -C `"$solutionFolder`""
```

Which I'm expecting to produce a value like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -C "C:\MySolution"
```

Instead, when the script runs (as part of a `NuGet` package installation inside Visual Studio 2015) I get this error:

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:3
+ ""C:\Program Files (x86)"\Git\bin\git.exe -C "C:\MySolution ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'C:\Program' in expression or statement.
```

I'm new to PowerShell, and though I tried suggestions from other answers, I couldn't get it to work (with failures of all different sorts).

Comment: Have you tried to use `"`s outside and `'`s inside, to avoid having to escape `"`s ?

Comment: @sodawillow I tried the opposite, but that looked like it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICS there's nothing wrong with your escaping, but you're misunderstanding how `Invoke-Expression` works. The cmdlet provides a way to run a given string as a commandline. However, PowerShell doesn't accept bare strings (in your case `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"`) as the command in a commandline unless you use the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`&`). Instead it will try to echo the string, but fail due to unexpected tokens:

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> "$env:windir\system32\ping.exe"
C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe
PS C:\> "$env:windir\system32\ping.exe" -n 1 127.0.0.1
At line:1 char:33
+ "$env:windir\System32\PING.EXE" -n 1 127.0.0.1
+                                 ~~
Unexpected token '-n' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:36
+ "$env:windir\System32\PING.EXE" -n 1 127.0.0.1
+                                    ~
Unexpected token '1' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:38
+ "$env:windir\System32\PING.EXE" -n 1 127.0.0.1
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '127.0.0.1' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

PS C:\> & "$env:windir\system32\ping.exe" -n 1 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

```
PS C:\> $cmd = "'$env:windir\system32\ping.exe' -n 1 127.0.0.1"
PS C:\> $cmd
'C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe' -n 1 127.0.0.1
PS C:\> Invoke-Expression $cmd
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:32
+ 'C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe' -n 1 127.0.0.1
+                                ~~
Unexpected token '-n' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:35
+ 'C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe' -n 1 127.0.0.1
+                                   ~
Unexpected token '1' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:37
+ 'C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe' -n 1 127.0.0.1
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '127.0.0.1' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Expression $cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

PS C:\> $cmd = "& '$env:windir\system32\ping.exe' -n 1 127.0.0.1"
PS C:\> $cmd
& 'C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe' -n 1 127.0.0.1
PS C:\> Invoke-Expression $cmd

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Meaning that you can just as well use the call operator right away and ditch `Invoke-Expression` entirely (as [@MartinBrandl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021212/1630171) already suggested).

```
$gitExe = "$env:ProgramFiles\Git\bin\git.exe"
& $gitExe -c $solutionFolder
```

Comment: As always, nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to combine the path and then invoke `git` using `&` and pass the parameter:

```
$gitExe = Join-Path $env:programfiles '\Git\bin\git.exe'
& $gitExe -c $solutionFolder
```

Comment: The `$gitExe` variable has other things run after it. For example: `$gitExe add -f $theFile`

Comment: then you probably should save all parameters in a hashtable and pass it to the `$gitExe` using splatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes inside the double quotes:

```
$gitExe = "'$env:programfiles\Git\bin\git.exe' -C '$solutionFolder'"
```

The other way round, variables would not be expanded.

Comment: That does not work in combination with `Invoke-Expression`.